# Angular app, masonry not a function

Tags: angularjs, masonry

I'm trying to use masonry with my first angular app. I have successfully used masonry before with no trouble but I keep running into issues with this one. I keep getting, Uncaught TypeError: $(...).masonry is not a function. Here is my code.

**Controller**

```
angular.module('cityApp')
  .controller('RestaurantsCtrl', function ($scope, locationsService) {

    locationsService.locations(locationsService.restaurants);

    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      $('.grid').imagesLoaded(function() {
        $('.grid').masonry({
          itemSelector: '.grid-item',
          columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
          gutter: 3,
          percentPosition: true
        });
      });
    });

  });
```

**View**

```
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

**Service**

```
angular.module('cityApp')
  .service('locationsService', function (ngGPlacesAPI) {

    var x, id, details;

    this.locations = function(type) {
      for (x in type) {
        id = type[x];
        ngGPlacesAPI.placeDetails({placeId: id}).then(function (data) {
          details = data;
          $('<div class="grid-item thumbnail">\
                <img src='+ details.photos[0].getUrl({"maxWidth": 500, "maxHeight": 500}) + ' >\
                <div class="caption">\
                  <h3>' + details.name + '</h3>\
                  <p> Rating: ' + details.rating + '</p>\
                  <p>Address: '+ details.formatted_address +'</p>\
                </div>\
              </div>\
            </div>').insertAfter('.grid-sizer')
        })
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: are you sure you have masonry.js loaded?

Comment: ... and jQuery before that

Comment: @Phil Yes and yes. I have checked to make sure everything is loaded and in the right order. I have jquery, angular, masonry, and imagesloaded in that order among my other dependencies

Comment: It's possible you're loading another copy of jquery and thus, removing any previously loaded plugins like masonry